# create JSON string from JS code with lot of mixed quotes

Tags: javascript, json, webdriver, escaping, quotes

I have this JS command I want to add to a  `<script>` to be put in `head` of an HTML doc (using a webdriver connection to the browser):

```
var links = document.evaluate("//div[@data-asin]//h2//a[contains(@href,'/dp/')]/@href", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ).iterateNext();
```

So, I would use jQuery command to send it like this:

```
jQuery('head').append("<script  type='text/javascript'> var links = document.evaluate(\"//div[@data-asin]//h2//a[contains(@href,'/dp/')]/@href\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ).iterateNext(); console.log(\'aaa: \' + links); </script>")
```

But I need to create a JSON obj to send it through webdriver, so I need to encapsulate this with another 2 layers of ' or ", one for the string, and another for the entire `"{...}"` and here I can't create it correctly with all those ' and " mixed together with \ escape ... Can you help me?

Comment: If you do not escape `<\/script>`  then you can only do that from an external JS file

Comment: JSON.stringify will add needed quotes. Also type=text/javascript is unnecessary

Comment: Ok, but how can I write this thing: json.stringify( "  jQuery(.....   "  ) with that added layer of quote, could you make an example please? I need it like '{ "script" : "jQuery(...." }' to put it into an HTTP Post in webdriver.